# Remove List Item Author

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, designer-workflow

I need a feature that would allow users to submit complaints anonymously. I was thinking of saving complaints in a SharePoint list, the problem is that Author needs to be empty in order to be anonymous. 
However, I have been having some trouble in trying to accomplish this.
I ended up using the following, but I was wondering if there isn't an easier way. Here's what I have so far:

1) Due to the fact that Impersonation Step was removed from SP Designer Workflow 2013, I created a Workflow 2010, that inside an impersonation step, creates an item in the SP list for complaints.
Actions inside impersonation step run with the credentials of the user who created the workflow.

2) I cannot initiate/trigger a SP 2010 Workflow using JavaScript so I created a 2013 Workflow which is triggered using JavaScript, and is responsible for starting the 2010 Workflow.

Is there an easier way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a Comment if a I could but not enough rep - but can you leverage anonymous access within your environment? If so, this TechNet post from the SP Dev team walks you through enabling anonymous access, which would then allow you to leverage the CSOM to save items to the list:
http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/06/13/how-to-allow-anonymous-users-to-add-items-to-sharepoint-list-using-client-object-model.aspx

If your goal/requirement though is to allow currently logged in users to add items to a list but not have their name be captured as the Created By, impersonation is your only choice, be it through WF or custom coded methods.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! Yes, I need to allow LOGGED users to add items but not have their names in the Author field. Is there any way to achieve impersonation using client APIs instead of server side code?